# Help dissecting a bash command used with LinkerD

Tags: shell

I'm currently writing a python script on a centos 7 VM which has to execute a couple shell commands along the way. I found a library which does the job, but I'm getting an error on one of them. I was given those commands from a text file so I don't actually know what they do. I understand simple ones, but these are above my level. Since only 2 lines get an error, I know it's not the script itself, but rather how I use it. `./linkerd` is [linkerd's](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2) binary file while linkerd_images.txt has a list of images:

```
./linkerd install --ha --ignore-cluster | grep image: | grep linkerd | sed -e 's/^ .*images: //' | sort | uniq >> linkerd_images.txt
./linkerd viz install --ha --skip-checks | grep images: | sed -e 's/^ .*images: //' | sort | uniq >> linkerd_images.txt
```

I do realize that since they use linkerd's binary, they might be unique to the application. If that's the case, then I'll have to figure out where I can find the documentation since I couldn't find it on their repo (hence why I came here first)

Edit: Here's the error I got in the script:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec: can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 49: Invalid continuation byte
```

If I run the first command by itself in terminal, I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '[Question Mark Symbol]'
```

I'm not so much worried about the error itself as I'm not really expecting a direct answer to my python code. I would just like to understand what the commands themselves do with all the fancy characters.

I have been asked to add the python code. I used `asyncio`'s [run function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) to run most of the shell commands. So the python code itself is simply:

```
asyncio.run(run(
     """./linkerd install --ha --ignore-cluster | grep image: | grep linkerd | sed -e 's/^ .*images: //' | sort | uniq >> linkerd_images.txt"""))
```

I also checked the linkerd binary file and it does look like a json file.

Comment: We can't help understand an error if you don't tell us what error you get.

Comment: I added the errors I get both when I run the script and when I run the commands by themselves in terminal

Comment: `sed -e 's/^ .*images: //*` looks like it is missing a closing single quote. If those two commands are exactly what you used, try fixing that first?

Comment: I just fixed it, thank you. I am still getting the same error though.

Comment: Does the two `linkerd` commands output JSON documents? Why are you in that case trying to parse them with `grep` and `sed`? Would it not be easier to do that with a JSON parser like `jq` (or a JSON parser library in your Python code)?  Would you be able to post the actual output of these two commands?  Also, since you call these commands from Python (right?), it would be helpful to see the actual Python code.

Comment: You say you could not find the LinkerD documentation? The ink you posted in your question goes to the LinkerD repo, and their README.md file points at the documentation website (https://linkerd.io/2.10/overview/).

Comment: @Kusalananda I added in the post the python code I used (although it should really just run the command in terminal without any issues). The file does seem to be a json and I have personally have never done this so I have no idea why I'm using `grep` and `sed`. My supervisor gave me some commands and asked me to run them in the script so I assumed they were good. I have a general idea of what grep does, but I honestly can't parse the file with pure python without knowing what the command does (hence this post).

Comment: Stupid things first: What you have in the question is a proper caret `^`, but the "unicode" errors suggest that possibly in your script it's some unicode combination with accents - some editors like to do this. Run e.g. `hexdump -C` on the script source and verify what it is (or ask your editor, if your editor can do that). A similar thing has happened to me multiple times when I copy&paste quotation marks.

Comment: @dirkt It gives me 5e which should be good. You scared me for a second considering the fact that we do indeed use them for accents. I also recopied the command, but manually changed that part to make sure it would be the proper character and I still got the error.

Comment: Next step is to take apart the pipeline. If the error is in the `sed` command, save the output that is fed to the `sed` part, have a close look at it, and try to reduce it until you find the part that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the answer I found**

The problem was not the caret, but rather the apostrophe. The person who gave me the command typed it with a French keyboard. Since it's on my work PC, I typed it here by looking at my other screen so I retyped a proper apostrophe without thinking about it. Now that I have looked into sed's errors and what they mean, it makes a lot more sense. `sed -e expression #1` is the first word after `-e` (in this case `'s/^`). Char #1 would be `'` which is where I should've initially looked if I had known about it beforehand.